# SQL Query MAX value attribute 1 and distinct attibute 2 with filter of double entries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I hope someone can help with my sql query.

I got a table looking like this:

> ID | post_id | likes | somemorestuff...
>
> 1 | 1000 | 5 | ...
>
> 2 | 1000 | 20 | ...
>
> 3 | 1001 | 7 | ...
>
> 4 | 1002 | 11 | ...
>
> **5 | 1003 | 19 | ...**
>
> **6 | 1003 | 19 | ...**
>
> **7 | 1003 | 18 | ...**
>
> 8 | 1004 | 17 | ...
>
> 9 | 1005 | 6 | ...

Now i need to filter them to MAX likes and distinct post id.

I found this code but its not working 100% in my case. It gives me the MAX likes and distinct the post id´s but only the once that r different to the max one. If there r 3 times the same entry, it will not be distinct. I need to filter out the double once. Hope someone can help here.

```
 SELECT p.*
    FROM posts p
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT post_id, MAX(likes) AS MaxLikes
        FROM posts
        GROUP BY post_id) grouped 
    ON p.post_id = grouped.post_id 
    AND p.likes = grouped.MaxLikes
    ORDER BY p.post_id ASC
```

Result looks like this:

> ID | post_id | likes | somemorestuff...
>
> 2 | 1000 | 20 | ...
>
> 3 | 1001 | 7 | ...
>
> 4 | 1002 | 11 | ...
>
> **5 | 1003 | 19 | ...**
>
> **6 | 1003 | 19 | ...**
>
> 8 | 1004 | 17 | ...
>
> 9 | 1005 | 6 | ...

Answer (score 0):

You need `subquery` with *correlation* approach :

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.likes = (select max(p1.likes) from posts p1 where p1.post_id = p.post_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySql 8+, you can try this:

```
Select * from
(Select *, Row_Number() over (partition by post_id order by likes desc) as ranking)c
where ranking = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select max(id) as id, post_id, likes
From posts
Where (post_id, likes) in (Select  post_id, max(likes) from posts group by post_id)
group by post_id, likes
```